# Botão em tabela para fazer update referenciando a linha

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho uma tabela, na última coluna de cada linha eu adiciono um botão. Preciso que ao clicar no botão faça update, minha dúvida é: Como eu vou referenciar a linha com o botão?

Por exemplo uma tabela com a coluna Matricula e outra Exculsão, ao clicar no botão Excluir da linha matricula 123, como sei que o botão é da Matricula 123? Preciso desse valor para fazer update utilizando o onClick.

```html
<script>
   function excluir(){
       // como saber a matricula?
   }
</script>

<input type="button" name="botao" value="Dispara função" onclick="excluir()">
```

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta para agregar conteúdo à sua pergunta, vale a pena dar uma olhada Felipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é passar o parâmetro para dentro da função, certamente quando monta esse botão você recebe esse parâmetro, então, basta passar para dentro da função no `onClick` que ele irá receber esse valor na função.

Exemplo:

```js
function excluir(matricula){
       // Aqui você trabalharia com seu código, o  alert é apenas um teste;
       alert(matricula)
   }
```

```html
<input type="button" name="botao" value="Dispara função" onclick="excluir('123')">
```

Answer (score 2):

Opa, blza!? 
Crie a função excluir que receba o parametro que deseja excluir:

```js
function excluir(matricula){
       // execute sua ação com o parametro matricula por ex: (123)
       console.log(matricula);
   }
```

```html
<input type="button" name="botao" value="Dispara função" onclick="excluir(123)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Criei dois exemplos para facilitar o seu entendimento, caso ainda haja dúvidas.

1: Se em sua tabela apenas existir as duas colunas mencionadas **Matricula** e **Botão**, você pode passar o valor da matrícula através do atributo `value` do botão Excluir da seguinte forma:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>stackOverFlow</h2>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Matricula</th>
    <th>Exclusão</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td> <button type="button" value="1" onClick="receberMatricula(this);">Excluir</button> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td> <button type="button" value="2" onClick="receberMatricula(this);">Excluir</button> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td> <button type="button" value="3" onClick="receberMatricula(this);">Excluir</button> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function receberMatricula(e){ 
       alert(e.value); // exibindo valor(matricula) passado pelo element button.
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

2: Caso sua tabela tiver mais de uma célula onde você queira tratar os seus valores, você pode manipulá-los da seguinte maneira:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>stackOverFlow</h2>

<table border="1" id="minhaTabela">
  <tr>
    <th>Matricula</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Peso</th>
    <th>Exclusão</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>André</td>
    <td>80KG</td>
    <td> <button type="button" value="1" onClick="exibirValoresLinha(this);">Excluir</button> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Túlio</td>
    <td>60KG</td>
    <td> <button type="button" value="2" onClick="exibirValoresLinha(this);">Excluir</button> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Hugo</td>
    <td>58KG</td>
    <td> <button type="button" value="3" onClick="exibirValoresLinha(this);">Excluir</button> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function exibirValoresLinha(e){

       var linha = e.parentNode.parentNode.children;

       var resultado = "Célula com resultados ";
       for(var i = 0 ; i < linha.length - 1; i++){
            resultado = resultado + linha[i].textContent + " ";
       }

      alert(resultado);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Nota**: Hierarquicamente falando, o botão passado por parâmetro`(this)` possui "pais" do qual vamos tratar para obter seus valores. Quando aplicamos o `e.parentNode`, nos referenciamos ao objeto `<td>`(*pai do elemento button*), e, ao aplicar novamente o parentNode: `e.parentNode.parentNode` é retornado objeto referente à linha  `<tr>`(*pai do elemento* ). Com o elemento `<tr>` em maos, utilizamos o atributo `.children` que retorna uma lista de seus elementos filhos`<td>` e nela contém todos os valores das células da linha. `var linha = e.parentNode.parentNode.children;`